# Can I have a Text Input control show a fact that a displayed text is truncated?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a Canvas App with a Gallery. One of the Gallery’s components is Text Input. Its screen width allows to display ~20 characters; whereas a corresponding DB field allows to store 40 characters; and sometimes this really happens.
My question is: is there a way that the Text Input somehow signalized to e and-user that looks at the Gallery: “please notice that there are more characters in this field; you do not see them”.

I know how to do such a thing with Text Label component; but here  have Text Input, not Text Label.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you can change the `Overflow` Property to `Scroll` for a **Label** Control.

[image]

For a **Text** Control, change the `Mode` Property to `MultiLine` to add an intuitive scrollbar.

[image]

[image]

If you want to get really fancy, you can insert an Label with some warning text below the Text Control and set its `Visible` Property to something like:

```
If(
    Len(TextBox.Text) * 8 > TextBox.Width, 
    true
)
```

[image]

Use a Rectangle Shape Control to measure the Width of each character of the text in your TextBox.
(Thats how I got `8` in the above formula)

[image]